# AG-grid cell-Renderer needs to re-render after button click

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I am using **AG-Grid** in **react**.

one of columns have cellRenderer named **actionCellRendering**. It includes three `pause`, `stop` and `info` buttons.

How can I update icon of buttons when they are clicked? for example change `pause` icon to `play`.

The below code shows minimized version of my code which is not working (due to not rendering again)

```js
export default function ActionCellRenderer(props) {


  const onPlay = () => {
    props.node.setDataValue('status', 'running');
  };

  const onPause = () => {
    props.node.setDataValue('status', 'paused');
  };


  return(
    <span>
      {
        props.data.status === 'running' ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPauseCircle} size="lg" className='rc_faPause'  onClick={onPause}/> :
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlayCircle} size="lg" className='rc_faPause'  onClick={onPlay}/>
      }
    </span>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. It only needs to define `props.data` as an internal state in cellRenderer function component, as below:

```
const [rowData, setRowData] = useState(props.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the click event handler with the buttons, and when a particular button's click event is triggered, you can change its icon to anything. Not sure how to do this in react.